# Easy way to get data between tags of xml or html files in python?

Tags: python, html, xml

I am using Python and need to find and retrieve all character data between tags:

```
<tag>I need this stuff</tag>
```

I then want to output the found data to another file.  I am just looking for a very easy and efficient way to do this.

If you can post a quick code snippet to portray the ease of use.  Because I am having a bit of trouble understanding the parsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

without external modules, eg

```
>>> myhtml = """ <tag>I need this stuff</tag>
... blah blah
... <tag>I need this stuff too
... </tag>
... blah blah """
>>> for item in myhtml.split("</tag>"):
...   if "<tag>" in item:
...       print item [ item.find("<tag>")+len("<tag>") : ]
...
I need this stuff
I need this stuff too
```

Comment: the so called "best" method is subjective. Depends on what is to be solved. If the task is simple, then use simple methods

Answer (score 2):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a wonderful HTML/XML parser for Python:

> Beautiful Soup is a Python HTML/XML
>   parser designed for quick turnaround
>   projects like screen-scraping. Three
>   features make it powerful:
>
> 1. Beautiful Soup won't choke if you give it bad markup. It yields a
>      parse tree that makes approximately as
>      much sense as your original document.
>      This is usually good enough to collect
>      the data you need and run away.
> 2. Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for
>      navigating, searching, and modifying a
>      parse tree: a toolkit for dissecting a
>      document and extracting what you need.
>      You don't have to create a custom
>      parser for each application.
> 3. Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode
>      and outgoing documents to UTF-8. You
>      don't have to think about encodings,
>      unless the document doesn't specify an
>      encoding and Beautiful Soup can't
>      autodetect one. Then you just have to
>      specify the original encoding.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like parsing into [element tree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and then using `element.text` and `element.tail`.

It also has **xpath** like searching

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree()
>>> tree.parse("index.xhtml")
<Element html at b7d3f1ec>
>>> p = tree.find("body/p")     # Finds first occurrence of tag p in body
>>> p
<Element p at 8416e0c>
>>> p.text
"Some text in the Paragraph"
>>> links = p.getiterator("a")  # Returns list of all links
>>> links
[<Element a at b7d4f9ec>, <Element a at b7d4fb0c>]
>>> for i in links:             # Iterates through all found links
...     i.attrib["target"] = "blank"
>>> tree.write("output.xhtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing it:

```
    (myhtml.split('<tag>')[1]).split('</tag>')[0]
```

Tell me if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath and lxml;

```
from lxml import etree

pageInMemory = open("pageToParse.html", "r")

parsedPage = etree.HTML(pageInMemory)

yourListOfText = parsedPage.xpath("//tag//text()")

saveFile = open("savedFile", "w")
saveFile.writelines(yourListOfText)

pageInMemory.close()
saveFile.close()
```

Faster than Beautiful soup.

If you want to test out your Xpath's - I find [FireFox's Xpather extremely helpful](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1192).

Further Notes:

- [lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/)
- [web-scraping-with-lxml](http://woz.thebigbluesky.us/a_curious_absurdity/2009/02/08/web-scraping-with-lxml/)

Comment: i want to remove the <italic>,</italic>,<bold>or</bold> tags for the text  with in the <abstract> </abstract> tags. so how to achieve it. for example                                             <abstract xml:lang="en">
<p>  Abstract-As     <italic>a</italic> promising method dealing with various wireless channel performance fading, <bold>MIMO</bold> technology is effective in supporting reliable, high-data-rate transmission. While the wireless system must cope with the space-time correlation and fast Rician fading.</abstract>                                        Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
def value_tag(s):
    i = s.index('>')
    s = s[i+1:]
    i = s.index('<')
    s = s[:i]
    return s
```